# Rails codebase scaling and changing on ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I'm currently rewriting our rails server code since many months have passed since our project began and there's a lot of dead code. We needed to migrate from Rails 3.2.12 to Rails 4. The issue is we need to rename some of our models and also need them to connect to the same `PostgresSQL`database (`ActiveRecord`) and `Redis` objects.

For example:

```
#api v1
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Redis::Objects
    ...
    attr_accessible :id, :text_body
    ...
    set something_redis_ids #redis object
    ...
end
```

To:

```
#api v2
class RenamedModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Redis::Objects
    ...
    attr_accessible :id, :text_body
    ...
    set something_redis_ids #redis object
    ...
end
```

That is I want to `RenamedModelB` to have its `id` and`text_body` from `PSQL` as well as the `something_redis_ids` from redis to point to the exact same items as in `ModelA`. How do we accomplish this? We prefer to basically rewrite the codebase from scratch so don't really want to build on top of our old, ugly `api v1`.

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question about the existing table names not matching your new class name? IF so, you can simply override it:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "PRODUCT"
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#overriding-the-naming-conventions

Comment: WIll this also change the redis-object parameters?

Comment: I haven't used it so I'm not sure. Most likely they allow you to override any key names as well.